# XMPP Java based client Library comparison based on architecture

Tags: architecture, xmpp, smack

I am looking for a comparison between different java based XMPP client libraries based on there architecture. I searched the net but I am not able to find the architectures of some of the lib I am specifically looking for like smack & emite. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Emite](http://code.google.com/p/emite/) uses xmpp communications protocol using the
[bosh](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html) technique and is written in pure Java.

[Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) is a good implementation in pure Java and is used in Android.

Can you specifiy in detail what you mean by architecture?

Comment: Hi Mark thanks for the input ... i am basically looking for a architectural diagram showing off different components and there linkage. based on this i will like to point out the modularity , scalability & extensibility of the solution.

Comment: Why don't you just send an email to the project owners. Perhaps they will help you. Or send them the link of this question :)

Comment: Ya i have already put the same request in the respectable forums ... lets see if i get some +ive response ...:)